# Replacing a deprecated filter 'woocommerce_get_price' with 'woocommerce_product_get_price'

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic, deprecation

I recently updated WooCommerce on a site that I didn't make myself. After doing this, then I saw the following line in the error-log:

```
woocommerce_get_price is deprecated since version 3.0.0! 
Use woocommerce_product_get_price instead.
```

But when I google `woocommerce_get_price`, then I can find no documentation on it, besides for this [hookr-page](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_price/) and [this page, where it just says that it's deprecated](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Deprecated_Filter_Hooks.html). But I can find no information about input and output for `woocommerce_get_price` and `woocommerce_product_get_price`. It feels like that it's simply a renaming, - but how do I figure out, if I can simply replace the name of that filter, without having to test everything page and function on the website?

It's a function in a plugin that has been custom-made for this suppliers sites. And the function looks like this:

```
public function woocommerce_get_price($price, $product) {
    $price = $this->get_user_discounted_price($price, $product);

    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to find because the hook name is generated dynamically.

All the `get_` functions in the WooCommerce product class, like `$product->get_price()`, use the `get_prop()` method under the hood. This is part of the `WC_Data` class that `WC_Product` extends. At the end of `get_prop()` the filters are applied like this:

```
apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $key, $value, $this );
```

And `get_hook_prefix()` looks like this:

```
protected function get_hook_prefix() {
    return 'woocommerce_' . $this->object_type . '_get_';
}
```

So all the `get_` methods like `get_price()`, `get_sku()`, `get_description()` etc. will go through a filter with the same format: `woocommerce_product_get_{property}`. In your case `woocommerce_product_get_price`.

For the new filter, the 2 arguments are the value, `$value`, and the product, `$this`. So it doesn't look like you need to change the callback. It should be sufficient to change the hook name.

Comment: I know this is quite an old post but thank you Jacob, it really helped!